# eslint config for exp init project

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I was compiling perfect way for adding eslint-flow-prettier in all types of react native projects.
I have some question about using eslint in Expo project. 
Does exp init also install eslint?
If not, I have tried using following command for installing eslint

```
1)yarn add --dev eslint eslint-config-airbnb eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y babel-eslint 

2)yarn eslint --init
```

**Is this the correct way to put eslint in expo project?**

In the second step above it asked to *Select 'Use a popular style guide'*, I selected Airbnb, after that it removed multiple packages and project is not running(obvious reason for error: missing libraries).
So why this is happening?
Should I have selected config other than Airbnb?(only 3 options for eslint config: Google, Airbnb, Standard)

Also I did use YARN for expo project because NPM was giving more complication, as it was removing 500+ packages during step1 above, which resulted in many of the libraries going missing from project, I tried npm install to install all packages but still had problems. So went with YARN.

For now I want to somehow include eslint in the Expo project.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE 26th March 16:25 IST:
1)Here is the info after installing eslint using: `npm install --save-dev eslint-config-airbnb babel-eslint` (npm version 5.8.0)
[image]

Comment: which editor are you using?

Comment: @AnjalSaneen, thanks for replying. I am using vscode, also the npm version 5.8.0, expo version: 50.0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem got solved by deleting node_modules folder in project directory and did `npm intsall`.
So, during any `npm install <package>` if it removes some other previously installed packages, only way for now is to delete whole `node_module` folder and perform `npm install`. This worked for me, when this problem occurred while creating react-native app with native code support(https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. install `eslint-config-airbnb` and `babel-eslint` as dev dependencies.
2. create a file in your root named `.eslintrc` and add this inside this file

   ```
   {
   "extends": "airbnb",
   "parser": "babel-eslint",  
   "rules": {

       }
   }
   ```
3. install Eslint extension in your editor. this is the [extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint) for vscode(you can enable eslint if you are using Webstorm)

Comment: should I use YARN or NPM?

Comment: @Raj it's your choice. I'm using npm. but i liked yarn too `npm install --save-dev eslint-config-airbnb babel-eslint`. this is the command for npm

Comment: there is some issue i am updating the question with screenshots